# Can I move the object pointed by a unique_ptr into a vector without copying?

Tags: c++, c++11, move, unique-ptr

Say I have a unique_ptr of a class Foo, and a vector of Foo's:

```
class Foo { ... };

std::unique_ptr<Foo> fooPtr = std::make_unique<Foo>();

std::vector<Foo> fooVector;
```

Now if I were to do this:

```
fooVector.push_back(*fooPtr);
```

If I'm not mistaken, this should create a copy of that instance of Foo in the vector; the "real"/original Foo is still somewhere in memory being pointed at by fooPtr.

What I would like to do is **move** the contents pointed at by fooPtr without copying anything into a vector (I wouldn't need the pointer anymore), this compiles:

```
fooVector.push_back(std::move(*fooPtr));
```

But I'm not sure if it's doing exactly what I want or whether it is "safe", as after this operation I still have fooPtr.

I guess it'd just be easier to have a vector of unique_ptr then move the unique_ptr ownsership, but I need it to be like this.

Comment: Moving is not magical. Moving is *shallow* copying (plus nulling the original if needed). If your `Foo` is deep (owns pointers to internal objects), then moving (== shallow copying) it is cheaper than normal (== deep) copying. If not, then not.

Comment: After moving the contents out, fooPtr holds a pointer to a moved-from Foo object. This is perfectly legal.

Answer (score 0):

`std::unique_ptr<Foo>` manages the lifetime of two closely related things.

It manages the lifetime of the *storage* a `Foo` lives in, and the `Foo` object that lives in that storage.

`std::vector<Foo>` manages both the storage of a buffer of `Foo`s and the lifetime of the `Foo`s within it.

The storage the `unique_ptr` manages is enough for a single `Foo`.  The storage a `vector` manages is a buffer for multiple `Foo` stored contiguously.  You cannot magically move storage around; it would be like moving a street address around.  You can pick up and move a house, but not the lot the house is on.

There is no single operation that both moves a `Foo` out of a `unique_ptr` and destroys that storage.

```
fooVector.push_back(std::move(*fooPtr));
fooPtr = nullptr;
```

the first line will move the `Foo` in `fooPtr` into the `std::vector` (possibly causing a reallocation and a bunch of `Foo`s moving around).

The second line clears the `unique_ptr` `fooPtr`, discarding the storage and deleting the (moved-from) object.

Anything that stored a pointer to `*fooPtr` prior to this operation will now have a dangling pointer, but there is only one (living) `Foo` object.

There are programming languages that do not allow objects to live in storage managed by anything except the programming language framework.  In these languages, an object and a reference to an object are mostly interchangable concepts, usually with gc to keep objects around as long as references live.

In C++, a `Foo` is actually a `Foo` stored right there, not a reference to a  `Foo` in storage managed by the language framework.  A `vector<Foo>` is a buffer *managed by the `std::vector` code* of contiguously stored actual `Foo`s, not a buffer of reference-to-`Foo` that other languages would tend to have.

This difference gives C++ about a 2x performance advantage over gc based languages, because programmers can make data be local and manage lifetime of data far easier than in other languages.  It places an extra load on the programmer, because it also forces the programmer to manage object and storage lifetime.